# Food safety of low temperatures like sous vide and slow cooking

Tags: food-safety, meat, slow-cooking, sous-vide

While I really like low temperature cooked dishes, I ask myself whether all microorganisms are killed with these methods. I'm worried that not all parasites and bacteria are killed at 60-70°C.

Is there a table with meat cooking temperatures and the corresponding surviving species that might remain in the products?

Comment: @rumtscho missing data on worm eggs

Comment: Food safety doesn't work by giving you raw data on the risks of worm eggs, or other specific pathogens. It gives you a hard limit for a safe temperature, and that's it.